# Evaluation of functional determinants

Tags: operators, regularization, wick-rotation, functional-determinants

Consider the evaluation of the following functional determinant:

$$\text{log}\ \text{det}\ (\partial^{2}+m^{2})$$

$$=\text{Tr}\ \text{log}\ (\partial^{2}+m^{2})$$

$$= \sum\limits_{k} \text{log}\ (-k^{2}+m^{2})$$

$$= VT \int\frac{d^{4}k}{(2\pi)^{4}}\ \text{log}\ (-k^{2}+m^{2})$$

$$= iVT \int\frac{d^{4}k_{E}}{(2\pi)^{4}}\ \text{log}\ (k^{2}_{E}+m^{2})$$

$$=-iVT\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\int \frac{d^{4}k_{E}}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{1}{(k_{E}^{2}+m^{2})^{\alpha}}\Bigg|_{\alpha=0}$$

$$=-iVT\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{d/2}} \frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha-\frac{d}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\frac{1}{(m^{2})^{\alpha-d/2}}\right)\bigg|_{\alpha=0}$$

$$=-iVT\frac{\Gamma(-d/2)}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\frac{1}{(m^{2})^{-d/2}}$$

---

1. In the first line to the second line, a common identity is used to write the logarithm of the determinant of an operator as the trace of the determinant of the operator.
2. In the second line to the third line, the trace sums over the eigenvalues of the operators of the determinant.
3. In the third line to the fourth line, the summation over $k$ is converted to an integral over $k$.
4. In the fourth line to the fifth line, the integral is analytically continued into the complex plane via Wick rotation.
5. In the fifth line to the sixth line, dimensional regularisation is used with the regulator $\alpha$.
6. In the sixth line to the seventh line, the integral over $k_{E}$ is evaluated.
7. In the seventh line to the eighth line, the derivative is taken with respect to $\alpha$ and then $\alpha$ is set to $0$. This step uses the fact $\Gamma(\alpha)\rightarrow 1/\alpha$ as $\alpha\rightarrow 0$.

---

1. Why are the eigenvalues of the determinant $(\partial^{2}+m^{2})$ given by $-k^{2}+m^{2}$?
2. Why is the conversion of the summation to the integral justified?
3. Why is the analytic continuation via Wick rotation justified - after all, the the integral is not defined on the complex plane, and the definition of the integral in the complex plane via Wick rotation appears arbitrary - why not use some other analytic continuation?
4. In the sixth line to the seventh line, how is the integral evaluated? How is the parameter $d$ introduced?
5. In the seventh line to the eighth line, how are the gamma functions differentiated? How is $\Gamma(\alpha)\rightarrow 1/\alpha$ as $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ used to obtain the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The operator $\partial^2 + m^2$ is a linear operator with eigenfunctions $\propto \operatorname{e}^{i k \cdot x}$ that have eigenvalues $-k\cdot k + m^2$. Apply the operator to the function to verify that it obeys the definition of an eigenvalue; for a linear operator $A$ that is $A\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$, with $\lambda$ the eigenvalue and $\mathbf{v}$ the eigenvector/eigenfunction.
2. The conversion from a sum to an integral is the same transition made from a finite Fourier series to a Fourier transform.

I'll leave 3 for someone else.

Comment: Would you please expand on point 2 - do you mean that the operator $\partial^{2}+m^{2}$ has an infinite number of eigenvalues, one for each value of $k$, which is why the summation over $k$ is replaced by an integral over $k$?

Comment: Yes, that's why the sum is replaced by an integral.

Comment: Is it okay if I edit the question to add more steps?

Comment: Not up to me, so go right ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the answer to 4 yourself. You used dimensional regularization. It is a tecnique that you find in every QFT book.

Answer (score 1):

Third question- no the integral is not defined in the complex plane but the parts of the contour that go off the real axis decay to zero as they are pushed to infinite leaving only the part on the real axis